# How to Add bulk before class in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have problem when I want create new landing page.

---

Class I use in header and footer was matched with class in content.
I was try use static css with header and footer. But code is to much. So I have a idea is will put css .head and .footer before class of menu.

---

This is my demo: https://xehondaoto.com/honda-city-test/
I was call https://xehondaoto.com/wp-content/themes/automotive/css/ajaxmenufooter.css

---

But ajaxmenufooter.css (this css is css of header and footer) have some code css matched class with landing page, like h1, h2, h3,...
So it was have affect to design (like padding, margin, size,...)
I want to change it like this:
Change from:

```
.car-p-features [class^=col-] { margin-top: 5px; }

.car-p-features i {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    margin-right: 4px;
}
```

To:

```
.head .car-p-features [class^=col-] { margin-top: 5px; }

.head .car-p-features i {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    margin-right: 4px;
}
```

It will not get confused class in header and landing page. Is this useful? And how to can do that? Can you help me?. I can do it with hand because Css of header and footer is very long.

---

Can you help me? I see some clip in this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j6j_53txI8A
I think it will useful but, I don't know regex replace like I want!

Comment: your from and to are the same

Comment: You can create a [wordpress child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), it will allow you to override the CSS without having to modify the big original CSS

Comment: This is html, I was try save design of different website to use for my site. Not use wordpress. I only want to add my header and footer to this landing page (HTML). If you know anyway. Try help me !!!